# How to have different colors for different list items in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I'm trying to do a task list using javascript (vue.js and node.js) where the elements of the list have different colors based on their properties. For example, if an item in the list has a property date that is less than three days away from the current date to have a red background color and items of the list that have dates that are more than three days away from the current date to have green background color. Is this possible to achieve this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You would create a method that takes your item and returns a style or class string, object or array.  Then bind the return value to your style or class.

```
<div :style='getStyle(item)' :class='getClass(item)' />
```

```
getStyle(item) {
   // your logic returning a style object
}
```

```
getClass(item) {
   // your logic returning a string, string array, or object.
}
```

You can find more details here:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html

Comment: Better to use computed properties than methods

Comment: not really.  this is per item, so you would need a computed factory for each item, and even then the computed would not be deep watching.  if the items are not changing properties dynamically, there is no point at all.

Comment: Then you have to consider creating a seperate component to wrap the content and moving the computed property inside that component.